# when Import into oracle 10g get error 6550

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-dump

When I am trying to import a file to a 10g database, an Error message (given below) appears. Anybody can help me with this?

> IMP-00058: ORACLE error 6550 encountered
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 33:
> PLS-00302: component 'SET_NO_OUTLINES' must be declared
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a mismatch between the IMP version and database version. If you use the imp that is in the same oracle bin directory as the oracle executable, you may have better luck. That may mean copying the file to the database server.

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE SIMILAR SITUATION .

But in my case we used to have oracle 9i and we used to use bat files to import data(database)
due to client requirements we were asked to upgrade to 11gr2 and we did with no problem
but when am trying to build a database from other client(we have all databases hosted on same server) i encountered

IMP-00058: ORACLE error 6550 encountered
ORA-06550: line 1, column 33:
PLS-00302: component 'SET_NO_OUTLINES' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully

little bit of googling i found out as i have two oracle homes.
i have to check environmental variables , you can check tat

To view or change environment variables:
Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
Click the Advanced tab.
Click Environment variables.
Click one the following options, for either a user or a system variable:
Click New to add a new variable name and value.
Click an existing variable, and then click Edit to change its name or value.
Click an existing variable, and then click Delete to remove it.

i found out in the PATH section 11g home was before the 9i home path . i just copied the path of 9i home which looks like C:\oracle\ora92\bin and pasted infront of 11g home path and my import command worked.

this may be one of the solutions,